# combinations in a circuit

Tags: combinatorics

> in a circuit there are 3 switches, of which 1 & 2 are in series., 3 is in parralel with 1&2.
>   all three switches can either be open or closed. how many ways of opening/closing all three different switches are there where there is electricity flowing through the circuit?

i would like to say $2!*2!*2!$ but that is for all combinations. What is the best way to think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $C_1$ the bit with switches 1 and 2 and $C_2$ the bit with just switch 3.
In total you have $2^3$ ways of combining you close/open switches as each has only 2 possible positions.

Now you need to count how many ways there are so that it no electricity flows through and subtract that from $2^3 = 8$.

For no electricity to flow through, you need both $C_1$ and $C_2$ to be open.
$C_2$ has only one way to be open that is to open switch 3. $C_1$ on the other hand has three different ways of being open. Both switches open, 1 only or 2 only.
So you have $1\times3 = 3$ ways of having an open circuit so $8-3 = 5$ ways of having electricity flowing through.

Another approach is to directly count all possibilities for the electricity to flow through. Because you only have three switches, I suggest you do a tree with each switch begin either open or close and for each combination of the three, deduce whether the electricity flows through.